# Prepare CV for first job: How does talent manager consider freelance profile

Tags: resume, first-job

I have been getting ready to look for my first job as a Data scientist and Software Developer while working on my Masters.

Here I am in a confusion. Should I mention my freelance career for a Junior Position? If yes, how does it help or how does it effect the decision making for recruitment Manager?

Comment: every piece of relevant information, especially work experience has positive impact on the recruitment managers decision making.

Comment: You should not use the general term "freelance career" which could mean anything but point to the projects you have worked on, list the skills involved and if possible provide a contact with the former clients who can verify that you did indeed work for them and to their satisfaction (which is pretty much how I got my current job after several years of freelancing). It helps a lot if you can explain how your freelance career relates to the position you apply for.

Answer (score 3):

As a hiring manager, I expect a candidate's resume to help me make a decision about the suitability of a candidate for a position.  That means I look at and consider *all* the data points available to me.

It doesn't matter to me if you're looking for a junior position or a senior position or anything in-between: if your freelance work is remotely related to the field you're going in to or are in then it's important to me.

Additionally, if your freelance work *isn't* related to the field you're going in to or are in, but it can speak to your ability to organize, communicate, time-manage, etc, then it's important to me.

Comment: The last paragraph is particularly important for entry-level positions - I don't expect an entry-level candidate to have all the skills for the job, but I *do* expect them to be someone who can function in a professional environment.

Answer (score 1):

Freelance career doing what? If you can't make an argument that your freelance career has anything to do with the type of positions you are seeking,  then putting your freelance career into your resume adds nothing but filler text to your resume.

If you feel strongly that your freelance career is relevant to your prospective employers, make an argument as to why your freelance career is relevant and include your freelance career in your resume.  No one is going to make that argument for you, least of all anyone who reads your resume - they, including myself, don't care enough about you to make that argument for you.